# What's the difference between iptables "state" and "ctstate"?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I saw this iptables snippet in a different Super User answer:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

The point is to always allow packets that are sent as a part of an established connection. The part I'm wondering about is the top two lines.

For the `INPUT` chain, what is the point of writing both `-m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED` and `-m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED`. It seems to be both should do the same thing?

An explanation of the difference between these two would be great.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Main answer :**

`Conntrack` supersedes `state`,
but in modern kernels there is now no difference between the two.
`State` is currently aliased and translated to `conntrack` in iptables if the kernel has it, so
the syntax `-m state --state`
is actually translated into
`-m conntrack --ctstate` and handled by the same module.

On some old kernels, however, contrack has to be specifically enabled.

**Possible explanation :**

It seems to me as if the rules you quoted included duplicates,
catering for both older and newer kernels.

Or maybe this is just a case of [Cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Answer (score 5):

There is [this question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/q/358996) from the year 2012:

> What's the practical difference between:
>
> ```
> iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
> ```
>
> Which one is best to use?

The [accepted answer](https://serverfault.com/a/359031) is:

> Both use same kernel internals underneath (connection tracking
>   subsystem).
>
> Header of `xt_conntrack.c`:
>
> ```
> xt_conntrack - Netfilter module to match connection tracking
> information. (Superset of Rusty's minimalistic state match.)
> ```
>
> So I would say -- state module is simpler (and maybe less error
>   prone). It's also longer in kernel. Conntrack on the other side has
>   more options and features[1].
>
> My call is to use `conntrack` if you need it's features, otherwise stick
>   with state module.
>
> [Similar question on netfilter
>   maillist.](http://www.spinics.net/lists/netfilter/msg46827.html)
>
> [1] Quite useful like `-m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -j MASQUERADE"
>   routing/DNAT fixup` ;-)

One of the other answers leads to this [document about `iptables`](http://www.iptables.info/en/iptables-matches.html#CONNTRACKMATCH). It says:

> The `conntrack` match is an extended version of the `state` match, which makes it possible to match packets in a much more granular way. It let's you look at information directly available in the connection tracking system, without any "frontend" systems, such as in the `state` match.

So I think this is true (from yet another answer there):

> There is no difference in the outcome of those two rules.

Note there is also an interesting comment under the question:

> `state` is deprecated in favor of `conntrack`, and may or may not be compiled in depending on how your kernel was built.

Comment: Note: for now this answer is just a bunch of citations from an old(ish) question. Anyone feel free to update it, especially if anything relevant has changed since 2012/2013.